# how to create an extra column and rows using select query in postgresql

Tags: postgresql

Following is a sample of what am trying to achieve (*never mind the select query because it just to show my actual problem*)

for example,

```
select col1 from(
select 'tab09' as col1
union 
select 'tab09_01' 
union 
select 'tab09_02' 
union 
select 'tab09_03' 
union 
select 'tab09_04' 
) t order by col1
```

will return

```
    col1
    ----------
    tab09
    tab09_01
    tab09_02
    tab09_03
    tab09_04
```

So, Which `PostgreSQL` function will helps to get the result like below

```
    col1       col2
    ----------+----------
    tab09      tab10
    tab09_01   tab10_01
    tab09_02   tab10_02
    tab09_03   tab10_03
    tab09_04   tab10_04
```

Comment: Just a tip: you don't need the `select` and `union` things to create testdata. `values ('tab09'), ('tab09_01'), ('tab09_02')` will work just fine and is a lot less typing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select col1,overlay(col1 placing '10' from 4 for 2) col2 from(
--your select query goes here
) t order by col1
```

---

[***overlay-postgresql doc***](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/functions-string.html)

Answer (score 0):

oh oh, i see a MAJOR problem here. UNION is definitely not what you want here. There is a major difference between UNION and UNION ALL. UNION automatically filters duplicates, which is not your goal. UNION ALL does an append. This is a very common mistake many SQL users tend to make. Here are some examples. I hope it helps: http://www.cybertec.at/common-mistakes-union-vs-union-all/
usually a UNION vs UNION ALL problems reaches my desk hidden as "performance problem".

Comment: The `union` in the question is only used to generate the test data (a complicated way of writing a `values(..)` clause.